# Is there an app.yaml setting to prevent the Datastore Admin from displaying only entities from the default namespace?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have no data in my default namespace (this is a Java app).

All of my data is in a namespace I have defined.

In my production admin panel, if I go to "Datastore Viewer", all of the data in my custom namespace is visible when I type the namespace name into the namespace filter.

However, the `Datastore Admin` shows NO DATA.

The `Datastore Admin` also does not seem to display an option to switch to my custom namespace.

I want to delete the data in my custom namespace and was hoping to use the `Datastore Admin` to do so.

Is there an `app.yaml` setting to get the `Datastore Admin` to display entities that are not  only in the default namespace?

Answer (score 0):

In the Datastore Viewer query tab, do you see '+ Options' ? Expand that, and you'll find the namespace override.